# Log file is created but File is empty

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using log4j.properties file for generating logs in my java project. I want only custom log statements and log file corresponding to that statements.
My log file is like this:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.axis.enterprise=DEBUG, stdout,Rollfile
log4j.rootLogger=off
log4j.logger.com.gridsense.server.automode=Rollfile,stdout
log4j.appender.Rollfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Rollfile.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.Rollfile.File=D:/javaProjects/AutomodeGS_Prachi/AutoGS.log
log4j.appender.Rollfile.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.Rollfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Rollfile.layout.ConversionPattern=[%t] %-5p %c %d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}  – %m%n

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x – %m%n
```

But when i run the program the log statements are printed on console and empty log file is created. I don't understand what is problem.Why my log file is empty?
In my class i have written the statement

```
private static  Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Driver.class);
```

I am importing

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
```

Actually I read your solution given to a question related to "Log4J file Empty" and made some changes in my code. I changed the import statement to

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
```

and in my class :

```
static Log   logger = LogFactory.getLog(Driver.class);
```

Still i encounter the same problem. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Did you add log4j.logger.yourPackageOrClass to your properties file?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
log4j.rootLogger=off
```

with

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,stdout,Rollfile
```

Comment: If i replace this log4j.rootLogger=off statement with log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout,Rollfile then i get all the log statements. But i want only selective statements so added log4j.rootLogger=off

Comment: Change DEBUG to INFO then only those logs will be printed which is in java file .e.g. logger.info("This line will be printed");

Answer (score 1):

There was no problem in your earlier code but the newer code is better as your code is not tied to log4j API.

Are you sure your application is loading this log file?

The rollfile will get log messages only from classes under package com.gridsense.server.automode. Are you sure there are some log messages executing?

Typically I have always used

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout,Rollfile
```

instead of below so not sure if it has any conflicts.

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.axis.enterprise=DEBUG, stdout,Rollfile
log4j.rootLogger=off
```

Comment: If i remove this log4j.rootLogger=off statement and add log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout,Rollfile this then i get all the log statements. But i want only selective statements so added log4j.rootLogger=off

Comment: You should have log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout and log4j.logger.com.gridsense.server.automode=Rollfile.

Comment: Hello , i found the answer. Need to replace following  statement 

    log4j.logger.org.apache.axis.enterprise=DEBUG, stdout,Rollfile
by

    log4j.logger.com.gridsense.server.automode=DEBUG, stdout,Rollfile

Answer (score -1):

The solution is very simple: 
**move the "Log4j.properties" file in the main Project directory**.

- if you have Log4j.properties file under any inner Package or Folder, then move it to main project folder.

[Properties file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nbtD.jpg)

Comment: Not necessarily. Some configurations will expect to find the log4j.properties file in a defined path.